# Django Form "'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm having quite some problems. In effect trying to add a form to a home-page with options for a user to select based on a DB object. Then once submitted the page will refresh, and the form can be used again.

Forms.py:

```py
rom django import forms
from django.forms import ChoiceField, ModelForm, RadioSelect
from .models import command_node


class command_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = command_node
        fields = (
            'host_id',
            'current_commands'
        )

        host_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            required=True,
            queryset=command_node.host_id,
            widget=forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                },
            )
        )

        current_comamnds = forms.ChoiceField(
            required=True,
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            },
            
            choices=[
                ('Sleep', "Sleep"),
                ('Open SSH_Tunnel', 'Open SSH_Tunnel'),
                ('Close SSH_Tunnel', 'Close SSH_Tunnel'),
                ('Open TCP_Tunnel', 'Open TCP_Tunnel'),
                ('Close TCP_Tunnel', 'Close TCP_Tunnel'),
                ('Open Dynamic', 'Open Dynamic'),
                ('Close Dynamic', 'Close Dynamic'),
                ('Task', 'Task'),
            ])
```

Models.py:

```py
from tkinter import CASCADE
from turtle import update
from django.db import models

class beacon(models.Model):
    host_id = models.BigAutoField('Id', primary_key=True)
    hostname = models.CharField('Hostname', max_length=200)
    internalIp = models.CharField('Internal-IP', max_length=200)
    externalIp = models.CharField('External-IP', max_length=200)
    current_user = models.CharField('Current_User', max_length=200)
    os = models.CharField('OS', max_length=200)
    admin = models.CharField('Admin', max_length=200)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.hostname

class command_node(models.Model):
    host_id = models.ForeignKey(beacon, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_commands = models.CharField('current_command', max_length=50, null=True)
    previous_commands = models.CharField('previous_commands', max_length=2000, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.host_id)
```

views.py:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import beacon
from .models import command_node
from .forms import command_form
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def home(request):
    form = command_form,
    if request.method == "POST":
            form = form(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return render(request, 'home.html', context)
    context = {'form':form},
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Relevant HTML section:

```html
</br>
</br>
    <form action="" method=POST>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {{form}}
        <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include, re_path
from .forms import command_node
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path('home/', views.home)
]
```

When I attempt to run the server or even now migrate I get the following.

```
PS C:\Python-projects\commandsite> python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python-projects\commandsite\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python-projects\commandsite\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 455, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 487, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 480, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 696, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 689, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python-projects\commandsite\commandsite\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    re_path('website/', include('website.urls'))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python-projects\commandsite\website\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .forms import command_node
  File "C:\Python-projects\commandsite\website\forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    class command_form(ModelForm):
  File "C:\Python-projects\commandsite\website\forms.py", line 7, in command_form
    class Meta:
  File "C:\Python-projects\commandsite\website\forms.py", line 14, in Meta
    host_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 1463, in __init__
    self.queryset = queryset
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 1488, in _set_queryset
    self._queryset = None if queryset is None else queryset.all()
AttributeError: 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'
PS C:\Python-projects\commandsite>
```

This was all working before I attempted to add a form in. Since tinkering with it to try and get a form this is the issue I face. So any help would be Greatly appericated. As I don't know what I've done wrong.

Comment: I'm used to seeing only `model` and `fields` in the meta subclass.  But you've put more.  Do those extra fields really belong in meta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, the error is raised because you're specifying `queryset=command_node.host_id` in your form:

```py
    host_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        required=True,
        queryset=command_node.host_id,
        widget=forms.Select(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            },
        )
    )
```

Actually, `command_node.host_id` is a `ForwardManyToOneDescriptor` (this is the class assigned to fields that are marked as `ForeignKey`). In this case, what you want to supply as the [`queryset` parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.queryset) is a set of objects that should belong to the model `beacon` which is the onea associated to `host_id`:

```py
    host_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        required=True,
        queryset=beacon.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.Select(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            },
        )
    )
```

This will display all `beacon` objects in your DB as options in a dropsdown in your form (the widget used is a `Select`). You could also display any queryset related to the `beacon` model. For example if you wanted to display only the `beacon` objects that have an internal IP equal to `X.Y.Z.W` you could sepecify `queryset=beacon.objects.filter(internalIP="X.Y.Z.W")`.

Some things to note here:

- Django already uses a `ModelChoiceField` when displaying the available options for fields that rely on a `ForeignKey`. You can check the associations Django makes between `Model` fields and `Form` fields here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types. If you want all `beacon` objects to be able for selection in your form, your code could be simplified to:

```py
class command_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = command_node
        fields = (
            'host_id',
            'current_commands'
        )

        current_comamnds = forms.ChoiceField(
            required=True,
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            },
            
            choices=[
                ('Sleep', "Sleep"),
                ('Open SSH_Tunnel', 'Open SSH_Tunnel'),
                ('Close SSH_Tunnel', 'Close SSH_Tunnel'),
                ('Open TCP_Tunnel', 'Open TCP_Tunnel'),
                ('Close TCP_Tunnel', 'Close TCP_Tunnel'),
                ('Open Dynamic', 'Open Dynamic'),
                ('Close Dynamic', 'Close Dynamic'),
                ('Task', 'Task'),
            ])
```

- A common practice in Python (and therefore in Django too) is to write class names in `UpperCaseCamelCase` instead of `snake_case` (see https://visualgit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/naming_convention.html#classes). If you adopt this naming convention, differentiating the class from its instances is easier.